# Could not find gradle wrapper with android sdk error (Visual studio+Ionic+cordova)

Tags: android, cordova, gradle

Visual Studio Build errors are:

Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.

Looked here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\tools\templates\gradle\wrapper

So far the solutions I have seen on Stack Overflow have not worked to solve my Cordova Android SDK error. I've tried changing path names, updating android sdk etc. Android SDK tools is updated to 25.1.7 and platform tools is on 24.0.2 and the error is strange as there is no \tools\tools\ , but it's still looking there even though I set Android_Home to C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\ as other solutions have suggested. Thanks for the help.

[System Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8BuV.png)

[User Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIjjD.png)

Comment: I got it to build by accident using C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\ is there a specific reason for this.

Comment: Sorry, how to solved that?

Answer (score 0):

You find the gradle in the below path not in the SDK PATH `C:\Users\your_username\.gradle`

Comment: I noticed this folder before I originally  posted my question. Is there any particular reason why when I see this question asked no one ever uses this solution? I always see them using the android_HOME path name android-sdk folder.

Comment: Do not set the android home path to tools folder. In windows the path is root directory of sdk only.`set ANDROID_HOME=C:\ installation location \android-sdk

set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools`